# How to make the input box in HTML to make it only accept IP ADDRESS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me with my problem.

How can I make my input box only accept IP Addresses whilst now allowing any text?

When I set the input type to `NUMBER` it disables the submit button, for example, the input box only accepts input for IP addresses like `192.168.206.103` and it doesn't accept alphabet. 
Here is my code:

Script:

```
function displayCam()
{
    var ip = document.getElementById('ipadd');
    var portz = document.getElementById('portz');
    //document.getElementById('camView').innerHTML = ip.value;
    var link = document.getElementById('camView').href="http://"+ip.value+":"+portz.value;
    window.location.href =link;      
}
```

CODE:

```
<h1>Input IP Address</h1>

<label for="ipadd">Enter IP Address:</label>
    <input type='text' id='ipadd' required="required" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX">



<label for="portz">Enter Port:</label>
    <input type='number' id='portz' pattern=".{1.4}" >
    <input type='button' onclick='displayCam()' value='Submit' required="required">

<div id="camView"> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to check if input is IP adress (probably using regural expression) every time `displayCam` is called or input is entered.